# Inverse Laplace transform of $\exp(-1/\sqrt{s})$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I'm looking for the inverse Laplace transform of:

$$F(s) = \exp(-1/\sqrt{s}).$$

Does the inverse Laplace transform exist? Do you have a reference in which this transform is given?

Comment: Have you ever heard of the Bromwich integral ?

Answer (score 3):

Since for every $\alpha>0$:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(s^{-\alpha}\right)=\frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\tag{1}$$
and:
$$\exp\left(-s^{-1/2}\right) = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\,s^{-k/2} \tag{2}$$
we have:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\exp\left(-s^{-1/2}\right)\right) = \delta(x)+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\cdot\frac{x^{k/2-1}}{\Gamma(k/2)}.\tag{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the answer be, "Does not exist?"  That is because, for inverse Laplace Transform to exist it is necessary that, $\lim\limits_{s\rightarrow \infty} F(s) = 0$.  Here, clearly $\lim\limits_{s\rightarrow \infty}e^{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}} = 1 \neq 0$.